# Get the string presentation of a resource key during runtime programatically

Tags: c#, .net, resx, c#-6.0

I have a .resx file.

I have this **key** "CustomerAreaIndexTitle" with the **value** "Hello Customer".

The value is not of interest here.

When I do `Resource.CustomerAreaIndexTitle.ToString()` I get the above value BUT... what I want is to get string representation of the resource key that is

"CustomerAreaIndexTitle"

Is that somehow possible?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use:

```
nameof(Resource.CustomerAreaIndexTitle)
```

It's a new feature in C# 6 and is *amazing* for things like this.

Comment: oh damn and I already used that for nameof(MvcAction) :F, thanks Matt